# WPA2 vulnerability and WIFI countermeasures for passphrase

Tags: wifi, wpa

Would frequently changing the passphrase through a physical connection provide a level of defense against recent WPA2 encryption breach techniques?

Comment: Better to ask the question in https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

No, changing the passphrase will not help, that has been covered in the announcement.

Use only HTTPS or a VPN.

For Windows and Linux get the patch, for Apple get the beta, for Android pray your phone will receive a patch.

For Linux and Android it is very serious because the key will be reset to all zeros, for Windows and Mac that will not happen because they did not follow the spec to the letter.

See [The Hacker News](https://thehackernews.com/2017/10/wpa2-krack-wifi-hacking.html), [Naked Security](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2017/10/16/wi-fi-at-risk-from-krack-attacks-heres-what-to-do/) and [Key Reinstallation Attacks](https://www.krackattacks.com).

Comment: Ok thanks good answer. Somebody migrate this and keep it in security i think this is going to be common suggestion.